# SELECT with WHERE using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have this method that selects movie showtimes by movie ID from a MySQL database and puts them in a Time[]. However, it is throwing a syntax exception near `'? ORDER BY schedule_id'` according to the [trace](http://pastebin.com/968Bqe0N).

```
public Time[] getShowTimes(int movieId) {
    List<Time> list = new ArrayList<Time>();

    try {
        sql = "SELECT schedule_time FROM schedule WHERE movie_id = ? ORDER BY schedule_id";

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, movieId);

        rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()) {
            list.add(rs.getTime(1));
        }

    } catch(SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }

    Time[] times = new Time[list.size()];
    times = list.toArray(times);

    return times;
}
```

I followed [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/) example (if that helps). What could be wrong?

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Hi, stacktrace added to the post ("according to the trace").

Comment: Please include the text of the stack trace in your post itself, instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `executeQuery(String)` method in your `PreparedStatement`, and that call is just inherited from `Statement`.  But `Statement` just executes the query without any `PreparedStatement` placeholder semantics, hence the error.

Instead, you want to call the [`executeQuery()` (no arguments) method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery--).  The SQL has already been prepared, and all placeholders have been assigned values, so the SQL argument string is not needed again.

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```